# Destructuring argument for key along with object in javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How can I get the passed in object `course` along with the `id` key  using destructuring the argument as in following code snippet ?

```
...
return (
    <div>
      {course.map(course => {
        return <Course key={course.id} course={course} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

For instance I've tried like(see below) this, but its not valid

```
...
return (
    <div>
      {course.map(({id} = course) => {
        return <Course key={id} course={course} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

*The object for reference*

```
const course = [
    {
      name: "Half Stack application development",
      id: 1
    },
    {
      name: "Node.js",
      id: 2
    }
```

Are there any way to do this or is it not possible yet?

Comment: `course.map( ({ id, ...item }) => /*...*/)`

Comment: @Dupocas I need the object also

Comment: `spread` args. Updated

Comment: @Dupocas I tried it before, didn't worked then, now its fine..working

Comment: Posted as an answer since I wasn't able to find a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Destructure `id` and `spread` the rest

```
course.map( ({ id, ...item }) => (
     <div id={id}> {item.foo} </div>   
))
```

Comment: This way item still is not the original, because its not having the id value now, also my use case want me to pass the whole object to react component, I think its not possible with destructuring currently...

Answer (score 1):

You can't destruct an object into its an element and itself.

It could be better destruct `item` in the callback function like below.

```js
console.log('-------Only get rest obj------');
const courses = [{ name: "Half Stack application development", id: 1 }, { name: "Node.js", id: 2 }];

courses.forEach(({id, ...item}) => console.log('rest obj:', item));

console.log('----Get full obj and destruct---------');

courses.forEach(item => {
  const { id } = item;
  console.log('id:', id);
  console.log('item:', item);
});
```

Comment: Actually whole point is that, I am trying to achieve avoiding any kind of assignment in function body..

Comment: You can not split an object into an element and whole itself concurrently. It is impossible. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
return (
    <div>
      {course.map(item => {
        return <Course key={item.id} course={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

You are trying to use the course variable again inside map function.

Rename outer most variable from course to courses.

```
return (
    <div>
      {courses.map(course => {
        return <Course key={course.id} course={course} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: No, answer is in comments above, you seem didn't understood the question..its solved I should use rest operator to get the object..

Comment: That's great, I just showed you another way of solving the same thing. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Consider below example

```
return (
    <div>
      {course.map(({ id, ...course }) => {
        return <Course key={id} course={course} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
```

It does gets us the `id` but `course` object does have all the keys of the original object(ie, it doesn't have the `id` now).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Generally, Stack Overflow prefers an explanation over "Code only" answers.  Consider adding detail on how this code answers the question.